# Adding markers to a kendoMap dynamically using a ko.computed and kendoMap binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am in the process of writing what is effectively an office locator.
As part of this I want to add markers within a certain radius of an initial location and put pins on a kendo Map control.

The jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/3whk8mm2/

I have the function below which filters the officeLocations array using a haversine distance calculation.

```
self.filteredOffices = ko.computed(function() {
        if(self.searchRadius() > 0)
        {
            var result =  ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.officeLocations(), self.filter);
            return result;
        }
    });
```

and the map itself is created using the following options:-

```
   self.mapOptions = {
        center: [53.4809500, -2.2374300],
        zoom: 5,
        layers: [
            {
                type: "tile",
                urlTemplate: "http://#= subdomain #.tile.openstreetmap.org/#= zoom #/#= x #/#= y #.png",
                subdomains: ["a", "b", "c"],
                attribution: "&copy; <a href='http://osm.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap contributors</a>"
            }, {
                type: "marker",
                dataSource: self.filteredOffices, //works if put self.officeLocations() directly
                locationField: "address.location",
                titleField: "name"
            }],
    }
```

I know that the filteredOffices collection is getting populated correctly as a there is a div above the map containing the correct results.

What I can't work out is why the filtered offices do not show on the map?

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markers don't update because `dataSource` option can't be bound to observable. As documentation [says](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/Map.html) observables work only with `center`, `zoom` and `widget` options.

To update your map you can subscribe to changes of `self.filteredOffices`:

```
self.filteredOffices.subscribe(function(value) {
   $('.map').data('kendoMap').layers[1].dataSource.data(value);
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3whk8mm2/3/)